Are these called "columns" of students or "vertical rows" of students?



Are these called columns of students or vertical rows of students? If they are called neither, what are they called then in AmE? I have circled the vertical rows of students in blue to know the thing whose name I am looking for.

We typically use row to describe things arranged horizontally or side to side, and column to describe things arranged vertically (as an architectural column in a building) or arranged front to back (as a queue of people all facing the door they’re waiting to pass through.

@W55 it looks like you have asked the same question twice, in different ways. Please edit one of the questions to contain all of the points that you want to make, then delete the other one.

But what about the students? Do they sit and stand in columns or not?

I think it would be more natural to say "students sitting behind each other", rather than talk of a column (which often means a vertical arrangement rather than a front-to-back). It would help if you explained how you want to use the word - what you say to your schoolfriends is not how it's described in an architectural diagram or school rule book. (And you sometimes hear "row" used informally for a line in any direction, but it's useless if you want to contrast horizontal and front-to-back.)

Column is the better choice of your two options. If you are looking at a group of people arranged in a rectangular grid like in your picture, it is obvious what you mean by column. I do not think there is a perfect word for what you describe.
"Vertical row" is confusing, since a row refers to a horizontal arrangement.
However, it would be unusual to ask people to arrange themselves in "four rows and six columns". You would almost always say "four rows of six people" (or six lines of four people for groups in the front-to-back direction). When used by themselves, "row" and "line" refer to a group of people oriented side-by-side or front-to-back, respectively.
Honestly, I think many English speakers would find a way to avoid the word, perhaps saying "the second person in each row" or something similar. For your first image, I would know what you meant if you said "line of desks", but in my experience this grouping is almost never referred to directly. You might ask the students to form groups with the people behind them, or ask the students to pass their papers to the front. The convention in English is to group seats by row, then specify the position in the row.
Though technically correct, I would certainly avoid jargon like "rank and file" unless you are discussing military formations or chess.
You may find this discussion helpful as well: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/118964/what-s-the-difference-between-line-and-row

While rows sounds natural when talking about people, column does not. In addition, in military parlance a column is used describe a block of, say, 20 x 4 soldiers. The term rank is used to describe the soldiers who are side by side, and file is used for the soldiers who are one in front of another. I'm not suggesting that you use these specialist military terms, because although most people know of them, few know exactly what they mean. I am merely explaining why column may cause confusion.
I can't think of a single word that would be appropriate in all circumstances: people generally express the idea in a different way that is specific to the circumstances.
If for example, the teacher wanted to hand out some leaflets, they would give leaflets to each of the students in the first row, then say "Take one and pass the rest back". Note that there's no mention of columns, lines or files...

@W55 that's a bit rude, especially when someone has posted an answer and done the research. Besides "column", "rank" and "file" are very much related.

@W55, you seem to be reading slights into others’ remarks. Try reading them with the assumption that we are trying to be helpful. “Seemingly deliberate” evasion of the point? I’d suggest you not wear out your brand-new welcome by insulting people’s motivations.

@W55, I have updated my answer.  Do you want to know how to deal with a specific situation, or do you just want a one-word-fits-all solution? If the latter, I think you may be disappointed.

We typically use row to describe things arranged horizontally or side to side, and column to describe things arranged vertically (in analogy with an architectural column in a building) or arranged front to back (as a queue of people all facing the door they’re waiting to pass through, though here file would be more natural, as in single file).
Thus a chessboard has rows, which are 8-square blocks running left to right, and columns, which are 6-square blocks running from one player to the other. But as @Chenmunka has replied here, they are often called ranks and files, respectively.
The term vertical row is not at all idiomatic.

I am still confused. Are those columns or files now? And are the students in the pictures standing and sitting in columns or rows?

“Are those columns or files now”? That wording seems to me impatient. Such curtness is not the best way to elicit help from others. I, for one, will not be bullied into responding further, not least because that would constitute rewarding incivility. I believe my answer is clear and complete as is. If there remains something you don’t understand, you are welcome to formulate a clear and specific—and civil—question.
